# Change of `DateTimeFormatter` pattern in Java > 8

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

Running:

```
Locale locale = Locale.US;
String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
        FormatStyle.LONG, 
        FormatStyle.LONG,
        Chronology.ofLocale(locale), 
        locale);
System.out.println("pattern: " + pattern);
```

Outputs:

```
pattern: MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a z   // Java  8.0.171-oracle
pattern: MMMM d, y 'at' h:mm:ss a z // Java 11.0.0-open
```

I found that Oracle uses the iana-tz database (https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html) for managing timezone data (see https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html).

However, I did not find anything about such a change of the standard date formatting. Investigating the source code, it seems that in Java 8, the function `LocaleResources.getJavaTimeFormatData()` loads the `sun.text.resources` bundle, while in Java 11, it loads the `sun.text.resources.cdlr` bundle.

My question is:
Is such a change documented somewhere, possibly with a reason for it?

Also, what is the best way to ensure compatibility with existing databases? For now, we have a list of recognized patterns, so I am thinking about adding the old patterns to my list of recognizable patterns by parsing the new patterns.

Another notable change is:

```
Locale locale = Locale.US;
String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
        FormatStyle.SHORT, FormatStyle.MEDIUM, Chronology.ofLocale(locale), locale);
System.out.println("pattern: " + pattern);
```

Outputs:

```
pattern: M/d/yy h:mm:ss a  // Java  8.0.171-oracle
pattern: M/d/yy, h:mm:ss a // Java 11.0.0-open
```

Comment: My `Locale.getDefault()` is en_US.

Comment: I've tested, and it's a change between 8 and 9.

Comment: Documentation: [Removed or changed APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096), scroll down to *Use CLDR Locale Data by Default*.

Comment: Also tested running with `-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT` on Java 9 (as per first dupe) and that keeps the behaviour of Java 8.

Comment: Best way to ensure compatibility of database across Java versions: (1) Store datetimes using the DBMS’ native date and time types, not as strings. (2) If you need to store strings, store [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.